# Nenhum membro chamado 'loadfile' em 'QGraphicsView'

Tags: c++, qt

Estou incorporando um código no meu programa usando o `Qtcreator` de um visualizador de imagens. Num determinado trecho uma função do tipo `bool` de outro formulário é chamada, mas o Qt acusa erro como se não houvesse função emitindo a seguinte mensagem:

> no member named 'loadfile' in 'QGraphicsView'.

Os includes estão corretos, tentei criar um objeto do tipo `bool` usando a classe do formulário de origem da função para chamá-la mas o Qt afirma que não há argumentos suficientes. O código do visualizador funciona perfeitamente quando roda isolado do meu programa. Mas ao incorporá-lo tenho esse erro.

Segue o código.cpp que está chamando a função do tipo `bool`:

```
void gestaoestoque::openImage()
{
    QString strFilePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(
                this,
                tr("Open File"),
                QDir::homePath(),
                tr("Images (*.png *.jpg *.bmp *.tiff *.tif)"));

    if (!strFilePath.isEmpty()){

        QApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
        QString strError;
        
        
        if(!ui->graphicsView->loadfile(strFilePath,strError) ){ /* Aqui ocorre o erro "no member named 'loadfile' in 'QGraphicsView'" */
            QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
            QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Error"),tr(strError.toLocal8Bit().constData())); //"Error displaying image."
            return;
        }
        QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();

        updateStatusBarInfo(strFilePath);
        enableControls(true);
    }
}
```

Segue o arquivo cpp da função que está sendo chamada:

```
#include "imgviewer.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QWheelEvent>
#include <QtMath>
#include <QMatrix>
#include "gestaoestoque.h"

ImgViewer::ImgViewer(QWidget *parent) :
    QGraphicsView(parent), m_rotateAngle(0), m_IsFitWindow(false), m_IsViewInitialized(false)
{
    m_scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    this->setScene(m_scene);
    this->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QColor(38,38,38,255),Qt::SolidPattern));
    this->setDragMode(NoDrag);
}

bool ImgViewer::loadFile(const QString &strFilePath, QString &strError)
{
    // clear previous and reset
    resetView();

    m_image.load(strFilePath);
    if(m_image.isNull()){
        strError = QObject::tr("Cannot load %1.").arg(strFilePath);
        return false;
    }

    m_fileName = strFilePath;
    m_pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(m_image);
    m_pixmapItem = m_scene->addPixmap(m_pixmap); // add pixmap to scene and return pointer to pixmapItem
    m_scene->setSceneRect(m_pixmap.rect());      // set scene rect to image
    this->centerOn(m_pixmapItem);                // ensure item is centered in the view.

    // preserve fitWindow if activated
    if(m_IsFitWindow)
        fitWindow();
    else
        this->setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);

    m_IsViewInitialized = true;
    return true;
}"
```

Comment: Para evitar longas discussões nos comentários a conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131544/discussion-on-question-by-marcus-vincius-nenhum-membro-chamado-loadfile-em-qg)